# Getting connection timed out error in microservice

Tags: spring-boot, postman, microservices

I have built a microservice using `Java 8` and `SpringBoot 2`. From this microservice, I'm trying to consume another REST API service. However, I'm getting the following error on `Chrome`. I have already disabled the windows firewall and McAfee antivirus firewall but still getting the same error. I can call the REST API directly using the Postman tool but not through my microservice.

**Error:-**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The underlying HTTP client completed
>   without emitting a response.
>
> 2018-06-12 15:21:29.300 ERROR 17996 --- [ctor-http-nio-3]
>   .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request
>   [GET http://localhost:8080/category/search]
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection
>   timed out: no further information: test.usdemo.xyz.com/92.54.41.24:443
>   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171] at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171] at
>   io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:325)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final] at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final] at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final] at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final] at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final] at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final] at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
>   ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final] at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_171] Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further
>   information ... 10 common frames omitted

**Controller class:-**

```
@RestController
public class CategorySearchController {

    private final CategorySearchService categorySearchService;

    @Autowired
    public CategorySearchController(CategorySearchService categorySearchService) {
        this.categorySearchService = categorySearchService;
    }


    @GetMapping(path = "/search-category")
    public Mono<CategoryResponse> searchCategories(SearchRequest categorySearchRequest){
        return categorySearchService
                .searchCategories()
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(
                        new EntityNotFoundException("No category matching " + categorySearchRequest.getSearchTerm() + " was found")));
    }

}
```

**Service class:-**

```
@Service
public class CategorySearchServiceImpl implements CategorySearchService {
    private String baseUrl = "https://demo0954903.mockable.io";

    @Override
    public Mono<CategoryResponse> searchCategories() {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(baseUrl);
        return webClient.
                 get()
                .uri("/category-search")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(CategoryResponse.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include jar file name for webclient class?

Comment: spring-webflux-5.0.6.RELEASE-sources.jar and package is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution for this issue. I need to add the proxy in the webclient as follows:-

```
private final WebClient webClient;
ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                options -> options.httpProxy(addressSpec -> {
                return addressSpec.host(PROXY_HOST).port(PROXY_PORT);
                }));

        this.webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl(BASE_URL).clientConnector(connector).build();
```